# prevent form wrong data and display error div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Prevent form from submit

I am trying to prevent the form to submit and display a warning DIV I have till they fix the wrong value.
When a seller try to selll a product for a cost less than the cost price it show the error

Here is what I have

```
<div class="warnings">error in price</div>
```

this is the div I show when the sale price is less than the cost price so we must prevent them to sell the product

```js
function hide(obj) {
    var el = document.getElementById(obj);
    el.style.display = 'none';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form#selling').submit(function(e) {
            $("#sale_price").mouseout(function() {
                if (Number($("#sale_price").val()) <
                    Number($("#cost_price").val())) {
                    $("#warnings").show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

I get no error DIV displayed and the form gets submited...

the FORM have the correct name and ID "selling"

the inputs in the form are

```
<input type="hidden" name="sale_price" id="sale_price">
<input type="hidden" name="cost_price" id="cost_price">
```

Comment: Unless I'm misreading something, I fail to see what this question has to do with Java coding, and so I've removed the [tag:java] question tag. You want to be more precise with your use of tags in the future, since tags and your question title are two very important parts of the question.

Comment: You could maybe delete the poor answer I got from llledhar

Comment: Your code is a mess, i mean... mouseout in a submit?

Comment: Yeah I see it hehehe it was a copy paste

Comment: please show the html form (the relevant parts). You have to call `e.preventDefault()` to , well, prevent the form to be submitted _before_ you do your check. And then submit the form if the check passed. (and there's no need for the mouseout, is there??)

Comment: I have the form name and id "selling" the input type=numbers name and ID sale_price and cost_price

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Why validate a hidden input field? I would just have used a `<input type="number" name="sale_price" min="300">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest returning `false` when the submission should be prevented.
Otherwise, even if the error is displayed, the form will still submit immediately afterward.

I've also corrected a few other errors, including removing the `mouseout`, ensuring all braces are closed, and using an ID for the error container rather than a class.

```js
$(function() {

  var $cost_price = $('#cost_price');
  var $sale_price = $('#sale_price');
  var $warnings = $('#warnings');
  var $form=$('#selling');

  $form.submit(function(e) {
    if (Number($sale_price.val()) < Number($cost_price.val())) {
      $warnings.fadeIn(150);
      return false;
    }
  });

  $form.on('click', function() {
    $warnings.fadeOut(150);
  });

});
```

```css
#warnings {
  display: none;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="selling" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="sale_price" value="300">
  <input type="text" id="cost_price" value="500">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<div id="warnings">error en precio de venta</div>
```

Comment: Just need to hide the div #warning on click in any place in the FORM

Comment: fount it function hide(obj) {

    var el = document.getElementById(obj);

        el.style.display = 'none';

}

Comment: I have edited to include a method of hiding the errors when the form is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

here is my example. I use javacript to validate if the input is less than another value and jquery to send that value to another file (e.g. submit.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Price: <input id="myText" type="text" name="price">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</body>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        try{
            var givenValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("myText").value);
            if(givenValue < 10){ //10 is an example selling price
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "submit.php",
                    data: {price: givenValue},
                    complete: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch(Exception){

        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Let me know what you think!

Comment: I need to check first if the value of price cost is less than selling price

Comment: My bad, then you need some javascript to do that. I will try to make an answer.

Comment: Have a look, I will also create a request example.

Comment: I made an example, I hope this is what you need!

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want, but since we don't see the actual form it's a bit of a guess.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form#selling').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form of beeing submitted

        if (Number($("#sale_price").val()) < Number($("#cost_price").val()) {
            $("#warnings").show();
        } else {
            $('form#selling').submit();
        }
      });
});
```

EDIT: now we have the form. This should still work, but showdev's answer is more elegant...

Comment: showdevs answer was perfect, the only thing left is that when I click in the input to edit the field value the div must hide, tries with onclick="$("#warnings").hide();" in the input but it does not work... any suggestion?

Comment: found it function hide(obj) {

    var el = document.getElementById(obj);

        el.style.display = 'none';

}